# Count number of entries based on month and year

Tags: date-and-time

I have the following sample data:

```
test={{{2020, 1, 1}, Brazil}, {{2020, 1, 2}, Brazil}, {{2020, 1, 1}, Brazil}, {{2020, 2, 1}, Brazil}, {{2020, 1, 1}, Brazil},{{2019, 1, 1}, Brazil}}
```

I would like to first group the data by month and year, and then count how many entries are in each group.

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
<|{{2020, 1},4}, {{2020, 2},1},{{2019, 1},1}|>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CountsBy` for this:

```
CountsBy[test[[All, 1]], d |-> d[[;; 2]]]
```

> `<|{2020, 1} -> 4, {2020, 2} -> 1, {2019, 1} -> 1|>`

Comment: Is there a way to not make it an association?

Comment: You can use `Normal` on the association to transform it into a list of rules, or you can use `Tally`: `Tally[test[[All, 1]], {d1, d2} |-> d1[[;; 2]] == d2[[;; 2]]]`